# WebView Stop Navigation

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently just goofing around, programming an Web Browser.

i wonder how to Stop Navigation from WebView just with a button click?
if there's any bool/void's involved in the solution, explain it please.

*Appreciate it!*

Answer (score 2):

If you are using WebView from WinRT, you can call `WebView.Stop()`.

If you are using WebBrowser from WP Silverlight, you can subscribe `Navigating` event and set `NavigatingEventArgs.Cancel` as true.

Reference:

- [WebView.Stop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.stop.aspx)
- [NavigatingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.navigatingeventargs.aspx)

Comment: Hahha i noticed before you wrote it! Thanks dude you got my mind 100% clear. xD

Answer (score 1):

You can do only using javascript,as below

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

   Browser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.execCommand('Stop');");

    }
```

Comment: I've already figured it out, just to let you know it din't work for me as you've written it. I need to implement a string with args for it to work. But still... Thanks dude, this might be helpful in tha future.